# Why do I have gnome settings on unity desktop?

Tags: unity, gnome

Last time I installed cinnamon and it broke my unity. So I removed cinnamon and reinstalled unity so after reinstalling I have gnome sitting on unity desktop.

And now I don't have minimize button for maximum programs (I have in full screen mode but I don't have in half screen mode).

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 13.10, Unity/Gnome are using same control panel `gnome-control-center`, You can check which logos you have in: `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/`. Then check from which package is coming from, example:

```
$ dpkg -S  /usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/UbuntuLogo.png
gnome-control-center-data: /usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/UbuntuLogo.png
```

Try reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data
```

In 14.04, `unity-control-center` was forked from `gnome-control-center`, See
[LSB shows different version than Control Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455823/lsb-shows-different-version-than-control-center/)